# How to combine labelling with limited boundingbox when plotting a geodataframe

Tags: python, labeling, geopandas, matplotlib, pandas

I am trying to plot a limited boundingbox of my geodataframe setting up some x and y limits to the ax. Everything works but the labelling. This is my piece of code and current result:

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(15, 15))
labels = []

xlim = [-24.213867, 16.171875]
ylim = [31.952162, 47.100045]
ax.set_xlim(xlim)
ax.set_ylim(ylim)

basemap = world.plot(ax=ax, color='grey', edgecolor='white')
grid.plot(ax=ax)
nearest_cities.plot(ax=ax, marker='o', color='pink', markersize=40)
nearest_cities.plot(ax=ax, marker='o', color='red', markersize=5)

for x, y, label in zip(nearest_cities.geometry.x, nearest_cities.geometry.y, nearest_cities["nearest_name"]):
    labels.append(plt.text(x, y, label, fontsize = 8))
```

[image: labels-with-bbox]

If I comment the last two lines, the bbox works. So my expected result would be like the following image but with labels on top of the markers. How can I make it work?

[image: bbox-without-labels]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I needed to add a conditional within the loop to check if the labels were located inside the bounding box:

```
for x, y, label in zip(nearest_cities.geometry.x, nearest_cities.geometry.y, nearest_cities["nearest_city"]):
    if xlim[0] <= x <= xlim[1] and ylim[0] <= y <= ylim[1]:
        labels.append(plt.text(x, y, label, fontsize = 8))
```

[image]